# Can i call CRON after create data in table of Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron

Can i set any way to call run after create data into table. I am using `Rails 4.`

Right now, my `cron RUN after every 3 minutes` but now  i need to call run auto when create user.

I tried lots but not found any proper way.

Any one have a idea or trick which i can apply.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you can write a rake task and call it `after_create` (callback is not a good option anyway, but if you need it).

Comment: you can use delayed_jobs in a callback. isn't that an option ?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko How to call rake task after_create? I did it but not run proper...give me some code or example link..